# Calling a data frame column through a function

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I'm trying to call a data frame column in a function but it keeps returning "None".

I've tried putting quotations and brackets around the argument to no avail. I thought since the keyword was formatted as such the argument needed to be as well.

```
def vehicle_data(vehicle_type):
    ser.loc[(slice(None), [vehicle_type]), :].reset_index().reindex(columns=col_titles_vehicles)

df_truck = vehicle_data('Truck')
print(df_truck)
```

The line of code inside the function works outside of the function by pulling the column 'Truck' from the data frame column titled ser.

Comment: Do you need `return ser.loc[(slice(None), [vehicle_type]), :].reset_index().reindex(columns=col_titles_vehicles)` ?

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output, so that  people can help you

Comment: @jezrael thanks so much! this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know I needed a return!